# iOS set timeout for url request in SDWebImage

Tags: iphone, ios, sdwebimage

I'm using SDWebImage library for caching image in my iOS app. Now when loading image from server I'm showing an activity indicator on the imageview. I'm using the following code

```
__block UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
  activityIndicator.center = self.serviceImageView.center;
  activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
  [activityIndicator startAnimating];
  [self.serviceImageView addSubview:activityIndicator];
  [self.serviceImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.service valueForKey:@"image"]] placeholderImage:nil completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
    [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
  }];
```

It works fine generally. But for some imageurls it didn't load the image and so it never comes to completed block & the activity indicator is spinning infinite.
So is there any way to set a timeout so that after a certain amount of time it gives me an error or something like that so I can stop the activity indicator.

It's bit argent. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the URL is valid, because when you pass `nil` to `setImageWithURL` the completion block won't be called.

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.service valueForKey:@"image"]];

if (url)
  [self.serviceImageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:nil completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
    [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
  }];
I
```

Comment: The url was ok, But that was not returning any image And I just see that It works for the first time fine. After that the SDWebImage blacklisted the url and so it was not calling completion block. I had to use option SDWebImageRetryFailed